# Mountain bike tyre at road bike pressure

Tags: mountain-bike, road-bike

Summary: A tyre that is 2.00 inches, or more, in thickness, that is designed to have a maximum allowed pressure or 7 or 8 bars, or 100-120 PSI -> does such a thing exist?

.............................................................................................

I've been obsessed for years about combining road bikes and mountain bikes into a single ideal bicycle.

I know about the options that already exist as compromises between road bikes and mountain bikes: hybrid bicycles (flat bar bicycles with tyres of intermediate thickness) and gravel bikes (road bikes that can go offroad as long as the terrain is not too technical).

But none of those options are good enough for me. I have imagined my own solutions.

It would take too much time to write all the details of the design that I have thought about here right now. I might write the entire design on this forum, but not right at this moment. For the time being there is one particular component that I think is the most crucial that I wish to ask about: tyres.

My design is not about compromise but about changing between "modes": a mtb mode and a road mode. The important detail is that I want a bicycle that is very good in those modes, not a compromise. So as an MTB I want to be a very good MTB. There's a lot of properties and components that affect the quality of a mountain bike, but for now, I'm focusing on tyres, so the more versatile the MTB the thicker the tyres are.

A thicker tyre is also slower on the road, especially if run at the low pressure that off-road-ing demands. So to create this swiss-knife of a bicycle, I have thought about this: a 2.00 or 2.20 or 2.30 inch tyre that I would use at 7-8 bars (100-120 PSI) on the road and 1-2 bars in the forest (15-30 psi). Good idea in theory, but does such a tyre even EXIST? That is my question.

Alternative related questions:
Can a MTB tyre be modified to resist 7-8 bars of pressure?

Can a tyre less than 2.00 inches (such as a gravel bike tyre for example) be made o be puncture resistant and not slide of the rim at small presure of 1-2 bars?

Comment: Are you aware that on road bikes, it’s now known that higher pressure often leads to higher rolling resistance? 120 psi is definitely not regarded as ideal. Also, a huge part of what makes an MTB an optimal MTB is the suspension, which would slow a road or gravel bike down.

Comment: following up on what @WeiwenNg said about tire pressure with a link to something Jan Heine wrote on the subject with some data https://www.renehersecycles.com/myth-16-higher-tire-pressure-is-faster/

Comment: The “higher pressure is slower” argument only applies to supple road tires. MTB tires on the road will lose too much energy due to casing flex.

Comment: The fallacy here is that you're expecting there is one single ideal bike that can be good/best at everything.  A MTB and a road bike have areas where leaning one way is advantageous on the MTB and disadvantageous on a road bike.  Like handlebar width.  So your "ideal" bike would be average between, ending up narrow for a MTB and still wide for a road bike.  A "do everything" bike is a compromise and therefore is great at nothing.

Comment: Aargh. That Jan Heine link again. The explanation kind of makes sense, but he just can't explain his measurement methods or even include one commonly available tire in the comparison with his favourites, there's no way to tell what the numbers mean or whether they are completely made up.

Comment: @ojs A bit more background https://blog.silca.cc/part-4b-rolling-resistance-and-impedance

Comment: @VladimirF That link is much better written, but it still lacks any information how the rolling resistance was measured and of course it doesn't include Heine's proprietary hipster tires. Also, if you have a close look at the numbers, they find that the break point for 25mm tires is around 7 bar, which is not exactly low pressure.

Comment: @It is not exactly small but notice that 1. the effect is there even for new asphalt and is sugnificantly eorde for just 2 years old one, 2. the penalty for having the pressure too high is much worse than having the pressure too low. I don't see any reason to concentrate on Heine's tyres whatsoever. GP4000s are much more common and a certain user here appears to be trully in love with GP5000s.

Comment: To the OP: just get a road tyre. MTB and CX riders like to get very low pressures for great cussioning and much better adhesion. In CX pressures below 20 PSI are not unheard of on 33 mm tyres. And it's worth it in the right type of smooth terrain.

Comment: Even you could get such a tyre, it would be an incredibly harsh ride pumped up so hard.  Take a heavy-duty touring tyre like a [marathon mondial](https://www.schwalbe.com/en/tour-reader/marathon-mondial) 35mm, and run that at its max 85psi lightly loaded and you'll see what I mean - I've tried it because that's what my bike came with.  BTW that particular tyre has a decent bit of tread, to the extent that I want to try it round my local trails and comes in a 2" version that will take 70psi.   It's slow for even a touring tyre, but faster than an MTB tyre and I've done 200km days on them

Comment: @WeiwenNg: "it’s now known that higher pressure often leads to higher rolling resistance" ...after a certain point, of course (_underinflated_ tyres do still increase rolling resistance).

Comment: @Vikki-formerlySean Correct. If you're familiar with the Silca link above, I was referring to the breakpoint at which the losses from impedance overcome the effect of increasing tire pressure. It's been shown that on a very smooth surface like a track or a steel drum, the old wisdom that high pressure is better is correct. But even on a freshly paved road, losses from vibrations will overcome the effect of tire pressure. That causes the sharp breaks you see in their graphs. I think that Poertner called out hysteresis as the mechanism that drives this.

Comment: Just run a race king at 35psi.  On smooth roads it'll be as fast as a cheap road tyre, and on poorer surfaces it'll be faster.  https://www.bicyclerollingresistance.com/mtb-reviews/continental-race-king-protection-2020

Comment: I'm not sure if the "old wisdom" was ever believed. Long before the meme about low pressure being faster was spammed everywhere Michelin included a chart of recommended pressures for rider weights with their tires and they were in line with the results in Silca blog

Comment: @VladimirF A thicnk tyre is my solution for enhanced grip. My goal is to have a bicycle which I can ride at high speed from home, or whatever, to a forrest, or the mountains, and ride the trails as an mtb. Well, I dont want the mtb part to suck. A road tyre would have too little grip. The idea is to reduce rolling resistance while on the road and increase grip on the off road. The idea is to use tyre width and low pressure for off road grip and high pressure for on road low rolling resistence. I need thickness and low pressure for grip because knobs are almost out of the question.

Comment: @VladimirF Look at Maxxis Holy Roller or schwalbe marathon mondial. That's about as knobby as i get realistically. I didnt mention in my original post because it was late at night when i wrote and posted it that in essence the bicycle design that I am interested in is that of a TT MTB. That would be a better alternative, for me, to a gravel bike. I already have an MTB that I converted to a touring bike, I will convert a 2nd time to a TT MTB. My bike is old and I want to buy a new one. This experiment will determine if I buy an MTB again or a gravel or CX bike or whatever.

Comment: @Biketouringfan if you are looking at holy rollers or marathon mondials you can solve your problem by instead looking at high quality XC MTB tyres.  They will both roll better on the road as well as providing more grip off road without messing around with changing tyre pressures

Comment: Realistically, at the speeds you are going to ride a MTB on the road, if you use a high quality XC tyre you will be losing at most 20W in rolling resistance, which will translate to less than 2mph difference - at the end of the day its the legs that do the talking

Comment: "Realistically, at the speeds you are going to ride a MTB on the road" - That phrasing suggests you think it's going to be really slow. As I wrote above I want to make modifications to my MTB to increase the speed on the road. Aerobars, larger front gear (chainring? I think it's called i'm not sure), locked out front suspension etc. My goal, if achievable, would be to achieve the equivalent speed on this TT mtb as i would reach on a road bike. As far as I know people can reach 40-50kph on a road bike. And on other forums some people told me they reached 40-50 on an mtb.

Comment: Honestly, if you are looking at 40-50kph, just get your mechanic to sort the bike out for you - or better yet, ride the road bike to the trails and then take the MTB off the top of the team car when you get there.  Be sure to mention stack exchange when collecting your olympic medal.

Comment: @AndyP If those values sound too unrealistic or too ambitious to you, they did to me too. And yet apparrently some people do that. Actually some people can do ever more. There was a presenter on GCN on youtube that got up to 70 kph on road bikes and even on gravel bikes while riding ON ACTUAL GRAVEL. But that uy is a former professional... I've had ordinary people tell they could reach 50 kph on a rode bike or even on a mountain bike in both real life and cycling facebook groups.I did not ask clarifications regarding if it was average or max speeds, only if it was on flat surface.

Comment: I'm not saying i'll riding at those crazy speed immediately. I just those speeds to be achievable. With my current set-up, designed with comfort in mind, it's probably impossible for anyone to reach 50 kph on my bike. So I need to make some kind of changes.

Comment: **Answers go in Answers, please**  Comments are not for discussion.  I don't like moving comments to chat because that's a graveyard.

Answer (score 15):

> 2.00 or 2.20 or 2.30 inch tyre that I would use at 7-8 bars (100-120 PSI)

Does such a tire exist?

No.

A little math...

The surface area of a torus is `4 x pi^2 x R  x r`, where `R` is the large radius of the wheel and `r` is the radius of the tire here.

Let's put a 2.00 tire on a 29er rim...

```
4 x pi^2
  x 15" (approx radius of wheel at center of tire cross section)
  x  1" (radius of tire's surface)

= 592 in^2
```

Assume the tire surface area is only about 2/3 of that, or about 400 square inches.  (It's probably more...)

Pump that tire up to 100 psi and each of those 400 square inches of tire surface has 100 pounds of pressure pushing on it.

That's a total of 40,000 pounds of force trying to push that tire off the rim.

Even if the tire can hold, the bead of the tire will be pushing ***HARD*** against the rim, trying to tear it apart.

40,000 pounds of force for a 2.00 tire at 100 psi.  Pump a 2.40 up to 120 PSI and it's more like 50,000 pounds of force.

There's a reason why tires have maximum pressure ratings, and larger tires have lower maximum rated pressures, and it's not because higher pressure starts to increase rolling resistance.

It's because high pressures in a large tire are downright dangerous.

Comment: You are right that big high pressure tires don't work, but you give the wrong reason. The real reason has nothing to do with surface area, and everything to do with tire curvature: It's the curvature of the tire that translates the pressure of the air into tension of the tire. A slim road tire has a lot of curvature, so it translates the high pressure into a low tension. A MTB tire would translate the same pressure into a much higher tension due to its low curvature. And it would tear at the rim with that force. Most likely it won't be the tire that fails, but rather the rim.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica can you do the math or give a link to explanation? Example of tire-like geometric form with high curvature *and* high surface area would be nice too.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica *The real reason has nothing to do with surface area, and everything to do with tire curvature: It's the curvature of the tire that translates the pressure of the air into tension of the tire.*  The only way for something to have a lot of curvature in a circular form is to be small, which means a small surface area.

Comment: @ojs It's a simple physics argument: A flat rubber sheet cannot exert a normal force because the forces within the rubber are all within the rubber plane. You need to give the rubber a curvature in order for each rubber particle to see a normal force due to its neighbours being slighty out-of-plane. Mathematically, the resulting pressure grows linearly with the second deviation of place along the rubber surface (which will also produce the correct direction of the force).

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica So to get the total force you integrate the normal force vectors from the tire pressure over the surface of the tire...

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, exactly. As to the connection with surface area, that's only as true as your shape is circular. The rubber is a 2D surface, and it can easily be infinitely large if the curvature is only along one dimension. The bike tire is a perfect example: It has two radii, and the small, crosssectional radius pretty much defines the curvature, and thus the relation between pressure and tension, while the large wheel radius makes the surface extremely large compared to a balloon with the same tension and air pressure.

Comment: @csmaster-reinstatemonica Right now I'm running a Schwalbe Marathon Mondial. It's rated for a maximum of 5 bars and I am running at 5 bars. I actually "cheat" and inflate it to 5 bars in the late evening before a ride, when it's cold outside. During the ride the tyre obviously heats up a lot which means even more pressure. This arrangement has allowed me to go a little bit faster, but in particular it FEELS much better, like smooth sailing. What can I expect over the long term? Bare in mind, it a tyre designed for heavy abuse - it's a touring tyre.

Comment: @Biketouringfan The mondial seems to be quite a good tire, and its pressure ratings are definitely at the high end of the spectrum. (I just found a 42mm mondial rated to up to 6 bar on their web site. That's a *lot*. Consider that a 28mm road tire of the same manufacturer only goes up to 8 bar.) I wouldn't want to push their ratings, they seem to be already near the max you can expect a rim to be designed for. Using disk brakes does give you a bit of leeway, though (no wear on the rim sidewalls!).

Comment: "I wouldn't want to push their ratings, they seem to be already near the max you can expect a rim to be designed for. " Okay, no more pumping in the cold. I will pump at the same temperature as what i expect to ride. So noon the day before instead of the night before the ride.

Comment: Well, plenty of much larger tyres exist for such pressures (e.g. for trucks or aircraft). Just not for bikes.

Comment: @Zeus [And those are downright dangerous too](https://www.google.com/search?q=tire+cages).

Answer (score 9):

No. It makes no sense to run a large tire at high pressures. As indicated in the comments, modern cycling has now accepted that higher tire pressure does not equate to lower rolling resistance in the real world.

Further, the ideal MTB tire (presuming there is such a thing, which there is not) requires tread to bite into soft surfaces. What tread pattern and depth changes depending on the surface - rock, mud, sand, hard pack to name a very few. Surfaces change from moment to moment, so choosing a mountain bike tire is far more complicated and important than a road bike.  Most MTB competitive bikers change tires for the conditions of the day, and many recreational riders swap between tires regularly, this despite the manufacturers spending decades looking to the ideal all purpose tire.

A better approach to the ideal bike is lower the cost of bikes to allow for a bigger N and S. (Refer https://www.velominati.com/ rule 12)

Comment: Picking the right bike for the job is fine up to a point but there are plenty of times you can only have one bike though maybe 2 sets of tyres - no storage, on holiday with only room for one bike, a single ride or tour on mixed surfaces. In the last case you'll probably need to compromise

Comment: Totally agree that one bike is often all you have for various reasons. (I am currently down to one). The trick is accepting that with the specialization in the industry (e.g. Gravel bikes)  manufacturers have actually made it possible for an rider to find the ideal compromise for them. The problem now is almost too much choice.

Comment: I seem to be in the position of having 3 - but trying to make them as versatile as possible anyway (rugged tourer, hardtail, hybrid with carrying capacity) so for gravel/dry dirt I could use any, and the MTB and tourer are surprisingly close in pace over some local tracks, at least until they get muddy.

Comment: @mattnz "requires tread to bite into soft surfaces" The theory I'm going by, at least currently, since I am revising this idea constantly in my head, is to compensate lack of thread (well, smaller knobs, or semi-slick) with a tyre as wide as possible and pressure as low as possible, in order to maintain grip off-road. Initially I thought about gravel bike tyres, but because of off road grip I came up with this idea: wide tyres and change pressure depending if i'm going on the road or off-road. But wider tyres means more rolling resistance on road. I want to reduce that with more pressure.

Answer (score 8):

Even though pumping up your MTB tires harder will help with reducing rolling resistance on the road, 100-120psi is far beyond what you need. 50 to 60psi is already getting too high, and most tires can handle that. However, not all rims can handle that kind of pressure, so you’ll want to be aware of that. Perhaps select wide road bike rims if you really need to go that high.

Ultimately, the thick tread, thick/stiff casing, and soft rubber used on MTB tires are guaranteed to roll slowly. At some point, you might be faster carrying a set of road tires to swap on when you need to ride on the road.

Comment: Yes. I routinely ride my hardtail mtb on the road to get to the trails. 45-50 psi makes for a much easier ride (2.1 - 2.3" tyres) but it's still not going to be as quick as my hybrid running marathon plus (and they're slow tyres). Depending on your off-road riding conditions, you can choose tyres that aren't too bad. In the dry I run wtb nano (more of a gravel tyre,with a thin smooth centre strip) but in mud it's nobby nic / rapid rob which are considerably slower. If the first part of a ride is long and on road,it's worth starting pumped up,and letting down,but not worth stopping to pump up

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. I thought about the idea that maybe it SHOULDN't be pressure that i;m focusing on. "the thick tread, thick/stiff casing, and soft rubber used on MTB tires" - I felt faster on schwalbe marathon mondial compared to maxxis crossmark which were my previous tyres. I rode those at 4.2 bars and the mondials at 5 and I thought the pressure difference was the reason i enjoyed the ride more. But I had a suspicion there was something else at play. Thank you for confirming my suspicion. So I should get stiff 2 inch or above tyre for the combo I'm trying to create here.

Comment: SChwalbe marathon mondials are touring tyres not mtb tyres so they are deisgned for other uses. I have made a mistake last summer of keeping the pressure up irrespective of terrain. That was some bumpy trail riding, I'll tell you that. So i havent had the opportunity to test this pressure changing idea. I am assuming even the stiffest tyres WILL bend and create more off road grip if the pressure is low enough, especially since i weigh 100 kg. It remains to be seen what my experience will be, but stiffer 2 inch tyres are lot easier (well... not sci-fi) to get than 8 bar 2 inch tyres.

Comment: @Biketouringfan No, for your use case, you want the lightest-duty MTB tires you still find acceptable on the trail. XC racing tires have sidewalls comparable to road tires, so most of the losses are in the wider tread and knobs. You therefore want to find the least knobby tire you can still happily ride MTB with. Wide, aggressive gravel tires are an option too.

Comment: @Biketouringfan Stiff casings are mostly found on enduro and downhill tires, which are most definitely going to roll too slowly on the road to be acceptable. Too much soft tread.

Comment: Well, now I'm confused. Stiff casings roll SLOWLY on the road? Soft rubber = good mtb tyre but slow on road. Right? So isn't the opposite of that a hard rubber which .... until i read your reply i thought meant an overal stiff tyre. I dont understand, honestly. Also, as I said I had some suspicions about properties other that pressure that made my current schwalbe marathon mondials better than my former crossmarks - by that i meant i noticed the tyre was more rigid in general even when it was more deflated. But you are saying a more rigid tyre is not good on the road?

Comment: "No, for your use case, you want the lightest-duty MTB tires you still find acceptable on the trail. XC racing tires"; Is the continental double fighter such an option? I was within a hair width of choosing the double fighter over the marathon mondials. Would I get even less rolling resistance with the double fighter than the marathon mondials? Btw, on another forum I was suggested dirt jump tyres, such as schwable billy bonkers. Those can be inflated to 5.5 bars and are 2 inch tires. Small knobbs, light threading. What do you think? Conti doublefighter or schw bonkers?

Comment: @MaplePanda "wide, agressive gravel tires" - Continental Ride Tour - Is this along the lines of your suggestion? https://www.bikexpert.ro/anvelopa-continental-ride-tour-puncture-protection-47-622-28x1-75

Comment: @Biketouringfan rubber hardness and casing stiffness are somewhat orthogonal properties. Even a hard compound will readily deform by _buckling_, if the walls are thin (compare with a flat piece of sheet metal – hard but not stiff). This can be avoided by increasing the pressure (analogy: putting tension on the sheet metal), or by switching to thicker but softer material (wooden beam: softer but won't buckle). Difference: the metal under tension is stiff also in directions you don't want it to, and fragile, whereas the wood beam can handle abuse by slowly degrading while absorbing energy.

Comment: @Biketouringfan Let us continue this discussion in the chat. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/214/the-velodrome

Answer (score 4):

You can't inflate wide MTB tires to road tire pressures. And it's not just that there are no tires that support that, it's just as much that there are no *rims* that support it.

The air pressure within your tire puts the tire under tension. How much tension is determined by both the pressure *and the curvature of the tire*. The slimmer the tire, the higher the curvature, and the lower the tension for the same pressure. As such, **a 2 inch tire at 50 psi has pretty much the same tension as a 1 inch tire at 100 psi**. All the pressure ratings for tires of different widths typically produce just about the same tension of the tire material.

Now, the tire tension translates directly into the force that the tire applies to the sides of the rim. Again, all tires within their respective rated pressures put just about the same amount of force on your rims, independent of whether they are road tires, or balloon tires. **If you create a tire that allows twice the pressure as normal tires of the same width, that tire will put much more force on the rims than they are designed to hold**. Most likely, you'd get a failing rim before you get a failing tire!

As such, no tire company wants to manufacture such tires, it would require them to also supply heavy duty rims, and explain to their customers that they must not use their tire with any rim that is not specially rated for the use of such a tire.

Comment: +1 for the explanation of tension, but I'd bet that good downhill- or dirtjump-targeted rims would have little problem withstanding 2" tyres pumped to 7 bar. Those rims already need to be quite overbuilt in order to survive the occasional “case” on jump landings, which involve much higher forces than the tension of even such a tyre/pressure combination. In fact, many dirt jumpers do run wide tyres at very high pressure. Wide tyres are needed to prevent cutting into the ground too much, but puncture protection and rolling resistance are more important than grip, hence high pressure.

Comment: ...what may not withstand such pressures is the _tyre beads_ – especially foldable kevlar ones slightly stretch so the tyre may blow off the rim.

Comment: In your opinion, what is the long term outcome? for what I've done last summer: inflate my tyres at night to 5 bars, when it's cold outside and then use them as such during my ride in the summer sun. I have schwalbe maraton mondials, rated for max 5 bars. They are touring tyres that are designed to be indistructible. My rim is a 26 inch mountain bike rim. I have yet to visibily see any destruction of the rim, but then again I am no mechanic.

Comment: @Biketouringfan the rim probably looks fine until it's in two pieces.

Comment: @Brad So I should perhaps pump i to 5 bars during the day or more generally at a warm temperature? Or do you mean 5 bars is enough to destroy the rim?

Comment: @Biketouringfan I mean to say that the failure mode people are describing here is not something that will happen slowly.  It's unlikely your rim will deform visibly, or your tire will stretch a little. You'll probably be fine, then go over a curb and then everything will go wrong. I'm not saying that guaranteed necessarily but I think looks can be deceiving.

Comment: The failure mode of the rim due to tire overpressure is: A stretch of the sidewall deforms outwards, possibly breaking off the rest of the rim. This stretch of sidewall thus looses its grip on the tire bead, which will be torn away by the tire tension, uncovering a stretch of naked tube. The tube won't be able to withstand the pressure and simply burst in the form of a long slit. You will immediately loose all air pressure in the tire, and the better part of the grip. If it happens in a corner, it's definitely a rapid unscheduled dismount. TL;DR: Your tire just goes *BANG* without any warning.

Comment: @cmaster - reinstate monica So I should perhaps pump it to 5 bars during the day or more generally at a warm temperature? Or do you mean even if i am careful not to exceed 5 bars there's still a chance it goes bang?

Comment: @Biketouringfan I'd fill it to 5 bar under normal conditions, whatever they are, and stop worrying about marginal gains. I would not consciously overinflate, even if I thought that there is probably a bit of error margin. But that's just me being a horrible stick-to-the-rules rider ;-) Your method of slightly overinflating is *probably* benign as the tires are designed to handle hot days after a streak of cold weather, but a 40% overinflation as it would result from a 2 inch tire at 7 bar is definitely in the danger zone.

Comment: Thank you.@cmaster-reinstatemonica

Answer (score 3):

The other two answers noted that large tires can't be pumped up to high pressures.

Let me explain a practical solution to your problem:

- Buy a gravel bike or hybrid bike with ample tire clearance (depending on if you want drop bar or flat bar)
- Build two sets of 622x19C rim wheels
- Put knobby wide tires on one wheel set (with these rims you can go up to 44mm)
- Put narrow high pressure road tires on the other wheel set (with these rims you can go down to 28mm)

If you want puncture resistance, there's a solution: [tire armor made of foam](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/75695/33932). My recommendation would be not to use this on the road bike wheel set, but on the MTB wheel set you may want to use it.

The only problem with this plan is that you have to decide which wheel set to install before going to ride. Thus, most gravel bikes have tires of intermediate width that are a compromise between road and MTB uses, simply because one has to ride quite a lot on a road before arriving at the MTB trail.

Comment: I use this solution with smooth tread tires on one set (higher pressure) and knobby tires on the other set. I use identical gearing so the changeover is pretty trivial if the rim width is the same on both. If the rims are different you may need to adjust the brakes.

Comment: Bike manufacturers would go far wider than 44mm on a 19mm rim (hence my MTB having narrower rims than my tourer) though I think they push it too far (hence my MTB squirming around at the back on hard stuff at mud pressure).

Comment: I am well aware of gravel bikes. They're not good enough for me. It was late at night when I posted this, hence why i said i didn't have time to go into details about the rest of bycicle. Well, the idea is, I want to ride a TT MTB. So MTB with aerobars. That would be the bike I would switch modes: a road mode (TT mode) and a mtb mode. I have an mtb that I converted into a touring bike, focus on comfort. This summer I will converted a 2nd time, this time into a TT MTB. If I like it, I will buy a new bike, a 29inch mtb in place of this 26inch mtb i have now and convert that into a TT MTB.

Comment: If I dont like it, I may be force to accept that it can't get any better than a gravel bike, or i go back to my original passion which has been to do bike touring at a lousy 20-25 kph. Either way my bike is old and I want to replace it. I have thought about this idea of mixing properties of road bikes and mtb bikes as a matter of interest into technology. But now that my bike is over 10 y old I now want to apply some of that. Or to get over it. Either way, the thing that prompted all this is I need to buy a new bike. Should it be another mtb or a gravel bike or a touring bike or a hybrid, idk